# Ratio of two independent standard normal random variables is Cauchy : a pathwise explanation?

Tags: probability

The ratio $N/N'$ of two independent standard (mean 0, variance 1) Gaussian variables is Cauchy distributed.

The computational proof is nice and fine, but does not explain why this happens; is there a pathwise/intuitive explanation to this fact ?

I know that Cauchy is the intercept of a standard BM started at $(1,0)$ when it hits the line $y=0$, or that Cauchy is the intercept of a random line passing by (1,0) and whose angle with the line $x=0$ is uniformly distributed on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of picking a pair of independent standard normal r.v. and looking at their ratio as picking a random point in the plane according to a bivariate normal distribution with parameters $(\mu_1=0,\mu_2=0,\sigma_1=1,\sigma_2=1,\rho=0)$ and looking at the slope of the line through (0,0) and your point. Since you're only interested in the ratio of the variables/slope of the line and because of the rotational symmetry of your distribution, this is equivalent to picking a point on the circle of radius 1, the angle with respect to the X-axis chosen randomly from let's say $[0,2\pi)$. This is equivalent to your second characterization of a Cauchy random variable if you think about it for a while.

Comment: Nice and clean indeed; rotational symmetry of the random point is indeed sufficient (when the constraint that the two coordinates are independent is added, then it forces them to be gaussian).